# Does high density altitude affect your landing speed?

Tags: landing, high-altitude

So I had this question asked in my recent commercial-pilot checkride:

The DPE asked me about high-density-altitude airports; he specifically asked me if I should add airspeed when I'm on landing approach to a high-density-altitude airport. 
 My total understanding is that the ground roll and landing roll would be affected, as well as the climb, but I've never heard about landing speed being affected; I've been looking in books and researched on the web but I can't get a solid answer.

Answer (score 11):

Your $v_\mathrm{ref}$ does not depend on density altitude since it is given in **Indicated Airspeed**, which already accounts for density effects. However, the **True Airspeed** and therefore also **Groundspeed** will be higher at a higher density altitude, resulting in more runway required to stop.

The Flight Safety Foundation has a nice summary of factors influencing $v_\mathrm{ref}$:

> **Factors Affecting the Final Approach Speed**
>
> The following airspeed corrections usually are not cummulative;
>   only the highest airspeed correction should be added to VREF
>   (unless otherwise stated in the AOM/QRH):
>
> - Airspeed correction for wind;
> - Airspeed correction for ice accretion;
> - Airspeed correction for autothrottle speed mode or autoland; or,
> - Airspeed correction for forecast turbulence/wind shear conditions.
>
> **Gross Weight**
>
> Because VREF is derived from the stall speed, the VREF value
>   depends directly on aircraft gross weight.
>
> The AOM/QRH usually provides VREF values as a function of
>   gross weight in a table or graphical format for normal landings
>   and for overweight landings.

<sup>([FSF ALAR Briefing Note 8.2 - The Final Approach Speed](https://flightsafety.org/files/alar_bn8-2-apprspeed.pdf))</sup>

Altitude, Density Altitude or Pressure are not listed as factors affecting $v_\mathrm{ref}$.